# Grep output - expected result?

Tags: bash, grep

I have the following grep

```
grep "/abc/[A-Z]" file1.txt | cut -d/ f3 | sort -u
```

The grep worked perfectly returning the results,

```
ALPHA
abc
BRAVO
CHARLIE
```

However, why is the `abc` in the output too? I have made the regex to only take capitalize words after the delimiter backslash. Is this an intended output and how should I remove the `abc` from the output?

Comment: grep prints the full line. `grep -o` prints the matching part only. Which would be e.g. `/abc/A` here, not `/abc/ALPHA`.

Comment: Thanks both. What will be a good strategy to get the desired result?

Comment: If the expected output is what you have above without `abc`, then you'll need to add  sample text to your question so that we have an idea of what you are working with.

Comment: Your command as posted looks wrong. `cut f3` reads a file called `f3`. You probably used `cut -f3`. Also, if you want the whole name to be uppercase, you need a repeat on the character range, and a terminator, like `[A-Z]+$`: your pattern only examines the first character of the field.

Comment: Read the current comments carefully and edit if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have not anchored the regular expression that you use with `grep`.  A consequence of this is that it may match anywhere on the line.

A line saying, e.g.,

```
blah/blah/abc/Abc
```

or

```
/blah/abc/Abc
```

would match your expression, and both would contain the string `abc` as the 3rd `/`-delimited field.

To anchor your expression to the start of the line, use

```
^/abc/[A-Z]
```

Alternatively, enforce a more strict match some other way, or weed out the `abc` result at the end using `grep -v -F -x abc`, whichever method suits your style and application the best.